# DynamicModule not plotting intersection region?

Tags: dynamic

I am trying to show and calculate the area of two overlapping, shifted hexagons using the following code:

```
Needs["Polytopes`"]; DynamicModule[{tv, r, pt, sup},
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
tv = Dynamic@TranslationTransform[pt][Vertices[Hexagon]];
r = Dynamic@RegionIntersection[{MeshRegion[Vertices[Hexagon], 
    Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]], MeshRegion[tv, Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]]}];
sup = Dynamic@Chop[N@RegionMeasure[r, 2], 10^-5];
If[Length[r] == 0, 
   Dynamic@Show[{RegionPlot[r], 
      Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Opacity[0], 
         Polygon[Vertices[Hexagon]]}, {EdgeForm[Thick], White, 
         Opacity[0], Polygon[tv]}}]}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotLabel -> "Area = " <> ToString[sup], 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-3, 3}}, AspectRatio -> 5.5/4], 
   Dynamic@Show[
     Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Opacity[0], 
        Polygon[Vertices[Hexagon]]}, {EdgeForm[Thick], White, 
        Opacity[0], Polygon[tv]}}], Frame -> True, 
     PlotLabel -> "Area = 0", PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
     AspectRatio -> 5.5/4]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out why the intersection region is not plotted.

I obtain something like this:

[image]

Comment: `Dynamic@TranslationTransform[pt][Vertices[Hexagon]];` does nothing. `Dynamic` updates pixels on the screen so whenever you have Dynamic@Something; nothing is being updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many `Dynamics` and in the wrong place:

```
DynamicModule[{tv, r, pt = {1., 0.}, sup},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
  Dynamic[
   tv = TranslationTransform[pt][Vertices[Hexagon]];
   r = RegionIntersection[{MeshRegion[Vertices[Hexagon], 
       Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]], 
      MeshRegion[tv, Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]]}];
   sup = Chop[N@RegionMeasure[r, 2], 10^-5];
   If[Length[r] == 0, 
    Show[{RegionPlot[r], 
      Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Opacity[0], 
         Polygon[Vertices[Hexagon]]}, {EdgeForm[Thick], White, 
         Opacity[0], Polygon[tv]}}]}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotLabel -> "Area = " <> ToString[sup], 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-3, 3}}, AspectRatio -> 5.5/4], 
    Show[Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Opacity[0], 
        Polygon[Vertices[Hexagon]]}, {EdgeForm[Thick], White, 
        Opacity[0], Polygon[tv]}}], Frame -> True, 
     PlotLabel -> "Area = 0", PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
     AspectRatio -> 5.5/4]]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notes: (1) In your code, you have a couple of assignments like

```
tv = Dynamic@TranslationTransform[pt][Vertices[Hexagon]];
```

This means that `tv` would never be equal to `TranslationTransform...`.  `Dynamic[code]` does not return the value of code.  It holds `code` unevaluated to be interpreted by the Front End.  When and if the Front End sees output to be displayed that contains `Dynamic[code]`, it shows the current value of `code` and updates it according to the rules of dynamic updating (which are complex).  This sort of assignment is rare, since one usually wants to use result, not just display it -- in your case, the translated hexagon `tv` is used to compute `r`.

(2) I removed the `Dynamic` around `Show`.  The use of `Dynamic` inside a code block is to mark code that can be updated and displayed independently of some other variables.  But the whole code displayed by the `LocatorPane` is a function of `pt`; it all needs to be evaluated whenever `pt` moves.

Comment: Nice explanation regarding the use of "Dynamic"